What is this SMD crystal marked AA51?
I have an SMD crystal marked AA51.
Please help me identify it from this picture:


Are you sure this is a crystal? With the package, I'd be inclined to think it might be a MEMS oscillator or something; crystals are usually in a metal can package.

It's probably a Citizen CM309S-24.000M crystal. The picture in the datasheet looks a bit different, but here is one from ebay that shows very similar markings.

(Source: ebay.com)
